# Remove functions from "this"

Tags: javascript

I have a function with a prototype function which contains a function on its `this`, like this:

```
function parent(){
    this.v = 0;
    console.log(this); // {v: 0}
}
parent.prototype.child = function(name){
    this.v++;
    console.log(this); // {v: 1}

    this.childOfChild = function(name){
        this.v++
        console.log(this); // {v: 2, childOfChild: [Function]}
    }
}
```

My question then is, how do I not show `childOfChild: [Function]` in `console.log`?

I know that it's possible, but I can't remember how to do it.

Comment: `console.log` is implementation dependent. Defining as non-enumerable may (or not) work for the short form, but most devtools will provide a way to inspect all properties, including non-enumerable ones.

Comment: @Oriol It works in node.js, that that's what's important to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define it as a non-enumerable property:

```
parent.prototype.child = function(name) {
    this.v++;
    console.log(this); // {v: 1}

    Object.defineProperty(this, "childOfChild", {
        enumerable: false,
        writable: true,
        configurable: true,
        value: function(name) {
            this.v++;
            console.log(this); // {v: 2, childOfChild: [Function]}
        }
    });
};
```

`false` is also the default, so you can just omit `enumerable`, too.